# why is this parse.com rest api request failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, curl, parse-platform

i'm trying to send a parse.com push notification from ruby 1.8.7.

i got a test working with curl. but with ruby's net::http i'm getting Timeout::Error: Resource temporarily unavailable

how can i debug this? i don't know how to see why the parse server is responding differently or otherwise see what's happening. i tried sending the request to my own server and the headers looked ok to me.

i simplified what i'm doing to this:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('api.parse.com', 443)
response = http.post("/1/push", "{\"where\":{},\"data\":{\"alert\":\"Elliot net http json test 1\"}}", {"X-Parse-Application-Id"=>"xxxxx", "Content-Type"=>"application/json", "X-Parse-REST-API-Key"=>"xxxxx"})
```

the json there is hard to read, it's from:

```
api_req = {:where => {}, :data => {:alert => "Elliot net http json test 1"}}.to_json
puts api_req
# {"where":{},"data":{"alert":"Elliot net http json test 1"}}
```

i also tried several other ways of sending a request with net::http. same result.

the curl request that worked was:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxx" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxx" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {},
        "data": {
          "alert": "Elliot curl test #4"
        }
      }' \
https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

i'm not using parse-ruby-client because i ran into problems with dependencies assuming a newer version of ruby. all i need to do is send some simple push notifications, and it seems like this should work without too much trouble.

can anyone help me get this working or tell me how to get some useful info about what's happening to debug?

Comment: What does your response from Parse return with?

Comment: like i said, i get Timeout::Error: Resource temporarily unavailable  (ruby exception, not http response)

Comment: `http.use_ssl = true` maybe?

Comment: that worked. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [REST API Developers guide](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/),

> All API access is over HTTPS, and accessed via the https://api.parse.com domain.

So all you need to do is to add `http.use_ssl = true`.